# Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Tags: web3js, bignumber

`const result = await myContract.methods.myMethod(1).call();`

brings the error from above. There is a simmilar questions here but since I use `call` gas shouldn't matter. I'm using "web3": "1.0.0-beta.35", (Beta.36 doesn't work for me at all.)

Comment: Use `1.0.0-beta.34` or `1.0.0-beta.37` or (best) `1.2.x` (which relies on beta37 AFAIK).

Answer (score 10):

Note that I believe this is fixed in the latest v3.0.0 of web3 which isn't out yet. This issue is now occuring for Binance Smart Chain. In the meantime, this fix worked for me:

https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/pull/3948#issuecomment-821779691

Comment: Nice seeing you around Mauvis! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Quorum?
If you are, this is probably because you are using RAFT consensus algorithm, you have to amend web3 or change to IBFT

Comment: changed `web3` --> `web3-quorum`, but still the same error

Comment: try to use web3-raft

Comment: tried it, but it doesn't work. here is a more detailed description https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65805/truffle-contract-error-number-can-only-safely-store-up-to-53-bits

Answer (score 1):

Try using **BigInt()** to resolve this issue. BigInt is an object which provides a way to represent whole numbers larger than 253 - 1, which is the largest number JavaScript can reliably represent with the Number primitive.

Example:

```
const balance = await contractInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
console.log('Balance of Account 0 =', BigInt(balance));
```

Comment: New error `TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number`

Comment: Same error as @TienDo. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

That is Javascript integer limitation (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`).

In order to work-around it, pass a `String` or as `BigNumber` instead.

For example:

```
const result = await myContract.methods.myMethod("1000000000000000000000").call();
const result = await myContract.methods.myMethod(new BigNumber(2).pow(54)).call();
```

Comment: In this case, `await myContract.methods.myMethod("1").call();`

Comment: @smarx: Yes, of course, but I don't see how this case (or any other case for that matter) could yield the error at the title. I guess he's doing something with the returned value which eventually causes this error (something which he hasn't posted here).

Comment: So you believe your answer is incorrect?

Comment: I don't do anything with the answer. I also tried with a sting or BigNumber but without success. As a workaround I'm using `truffle-contract` now which works fine.

Comment: @smarx: No, I believe that the question is missing some info. Either that, or there's a serious bug in `"web3": "1.0.0-beta.35"`, which I sincerely doubt (though I've been using 34 for quite some time, so I'm possibly wrong on that one).

Comment: I'm not sure why you submitted this answer if you didn't think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

This will also happen if you set `gasPrice` to be some very large value when sending transaction like: `15e64`.

Answer (score 0):

In many blogs I've found it was a Truffle version problem. Truffle v5 would make problems of this type. They suggest to downgrade to truffle@4.1.15.

This has not been so for me. I have continue to use truffle v5. I've resolved by checking my gas limit when I sent a transaction.
gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex( gas_limit ),//The maximum gas provided for this transaction (gas limit)

Node: v8.11.4
Truffle: 5.0.12
Web3: 1.0.0-beta.52
Truffle-contract: 4.0.11
Truffle-interface-adapter@0.1.2
│ └── web3@1.0.0-beta.37
└── web3@1.0.0-beta.37
Ganache-cli: v6.4.3 (ganache-core: 2.5.5)
Ethereumjs-tx: 1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Check the contract code again please, You may have added some **require(msg.sender == owner)** like modifier and you code doesn't return some data which can be processed in client side.

Answer (score 0):

**Ultimate Solution**

Simple install web3 latest version which is version 4

`npm install web3@v4.0.1-alpha.1`

That solved my problem