# truffle-contract error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Tags: contract-invocation, truffle-contract, quorum

I am using `truffle-contract` with a local `quorum` node and try to execute a smart contract method, but getting this error:

> Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

That's the way I do it:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:22000'));

const ContractJSON = require('./build/contracts/MyContract.json');

//setting up for truffle-contract
var MyContract = truffleContract({
    abi: ContractJSON.abi,
    unlinked_binary: ContractJSON.bin,
    address: ContractJSON.address
});
MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

var contract;
MyContract.deployed().then(instance => { 
    contract = instance;
    contract.myContractMethod(
        web3.utils.toHex('abc123'),       //bytes32
        Number(123));                     //uint256
})
.then(result => { console.log("RESULT " + result); })
.catch(err => { console.log("ERROR! " + err); });
```

The contract itself works and I can also interact with it using `truffle console`, but `truffle-contract` gives me the above mentioned error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it works if you use BigNumber from web3? ie `web3.utils.toBN(123)`.

Comment: No still the same error

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with the new Truffle version (using on Quorum).

`truffle` v5 and `truffle-contract` v4 don't work.

Using the latest v3 `truffle-contract@3.0.7` solved this particular issue.

Comment: Truffle v5 seems to have a few issues still, especially with Quorum. We currently advise to use Truffle v4.1.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

In many blogs I've found it was a Truffle version problem. Truffle v5 would make problems of this type. They suggest to downgrade to truffle@4.1.15.

This has not been so for me. I have continue to use truffle v5. I've resolved by checking my gas limit when I sent a transaction.
gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex( gas_limit ),//The maximum gas provided for this transaction (gas limit)

Node: v8.11.4
Truffle: 5.0.12
Web3: 1.0.0-beta.52
Truffle-contract: 4.0.11
Truffle-interface-adapter@0.1.2
│ └── web3@1.0.0-beta.37
└── web3@1.0.0-beta.37
Ganache-cli: v6.4.3 (ganache-core: 2.5.5)
Ethereumjs-tx: 1.3.4